# is /1234 a valid topic name

Tags: ros, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to know if /1234 a valid topic name ? Any where mention the requirement of topic name ?
Thank you
Edwin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217961/is-/1234-a-valid-topic-name/) by [elthef](https://answers.ros.org/users/9256/elthef/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2015-09-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Naming conventions can be found here: http://wiki.ros.org/Names

1.1.1 Valid Names

A valid name has the following characteristics:

1. First character is an alpha
   character ([a-z|A-Z]), tilde (~) or
   forward slash (/)
2. Subsequent characters can be alphanumeric ([0-9|a-z|A-Z]),
   underscores (_), or forward slashes
   (/)

Your name starts with a "/" and then consists of alphanumeric charactes, so it's a valid topic name.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2015-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-09-21**:
Correct information cited, but the first character is only alpha, not alphanumeric. So this is NOT a valid topic name.

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2015-09-21**:
The first character is a forward slash, which is a valid first character. (And I can create a publisher for this topic without problems or warnings.)

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-09-21**:
Interesting. It seems that a topic like /_ would be valid.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-06-20**:
The intent is that each token must start with an alpha. The ~ is a special replacement and the / is a joiner. I don't know how it's exactly enforced in the different implementations. In the spirit of things starting with a number for a token is not valid.